# Facebook social plugins not always showing up

Tags: html, facebook, fbml

Im added few weeks ago a like button and comments to my website and for some reason - its not always showing up.

http://www.raal.co.il/content/view/58/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%97%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%97%D7%99%D7%93%D7%AA-%D7%93%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93%D7%91%D7%9F

heres an example, on the bottom part of the page there should be a comment box, its only occasionally appears..

on the top part on the right side (near the share button) theres a recommend button.. also.. only occasionally appears.

thanks!

(IM USING CHROME)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add `xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"` to your `<html>` declaration, then consider explicitly invoking `FB.XFBML.parse()` in your init callback.

Comment: where exactly would you place `FB.XFBML.parse();`? i tried `window.onload = function() {
  FB.XFBML.parse();
 }`  chrome on pc is not displaying social plugins